# Ruby on Rails, No template for interactive request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, react-rails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roT9c.png)

I previously run the

```
rails generate controller Welcome index
```

command on terminal and just directly run the server, but this error message keep occuring:

> No template for interactive request
>   WelcomeController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

I have tried looking for solutions but none can resolve the issue.

These are the file path
[image]

and inside it only contains:

## Hello,Rails!

Comment: Are there any codes?

Comment: You have to add a view file at app/views/welcome/index.html.erb https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: @arieljuod The file was generated automatically by the rails when i generate the controller so I don't need to add a new file on my own right?

Comment: @UdoE. The codes were the default code generated when creating the controller. I have not modified anything yet.. and just wanna straightly running the server.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error as well. Turns out I accidentally had the folder that had my html.erb files inside of my `layouts`.

`views/layouts/welcome/index.html` <- wrong

`views/welcome/index.html` <- correct

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution to my problem. But I was confused why. Previously, I run the rails server on a git bash command line and it keeps spitting out the error message I show above. But then, I try to make a new app using Windows command line and repeat the same steps and run the server and it works! I was wondering what happen with my git bash command line. Does it have to do with PATH? or maybe I was missing something when I installed git bash?

The reason i said that is because when I run the rails server on my Windows command line, I saw that there is a [compiling...] step before finally running my server, but this steps does not occur when I run rails server on git bash. Can anybody provide an explanation about this?

Sorry, for the long-winded message. I am truly new to rails-react!! Thanks..

Comment: This solved my issue. The classic CMD did the trick

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and I managed to resolve it by ensuring the file paths were free of spaces. In my case my mounted drive was called "HDD (Mint)" changing it to "HDD-Mint" resolved this.

Comment: I dont get which drive you meant previously

Comment: I am sorry I am not very clear about the drive rename action.. Is it the name of the project(app) that we rename?

Comment: if my ruby files is in the C: drive, should I make the project in C drive as well? It does not matter anyway right?? @Zhorian

Comment: Changed my drive name to no spaces, but still does not resolve the issue

Comment: I'm using linux not windows so the root to my project is /mnt/HDD-Mint/Repo/udemy-ror/projects/intro if think the whole path needs to be devoid of spaces but I could be wrong. I just know this sorted my problem out.

Answer (score 2):

just to add to @Zhorian's answer...

I resolved my error by removing special characters from the folders in the filepath as well (parentheses, in my case).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't use **spaces** and/or **parenthesis** in your Rails pathname, for example:

```
\Users\username\Dropbox (company)\my_rails_app
```

So this problem currently occurs when working with Dropbox Business.

It's considered as a bug in Rails, a fix has already been made, but not yet available in the Rails version 6.0.2.1

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37119
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37719
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37641

P.S.
I think the 'space' problem was fixed already before, but the 'parenthesis' problem still remained in Rails 6.0.2.1

Comment: Thanks for this, been driving me mad for hours trying to work out what I was doing wrong. :-/

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error on a Linux Centos 7, no special charachters nor whitespaces in the path.
Also my templates are in place, I see in the log that they are being rendered.

Comment: @Phipsen Out of curiousity, what is the absolute path you use?

Comment: @PaulVerschoor: I needed to add a subdir for the template. Was posting a separate question and did get an answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540462/rails-6-0-2-actionmailer-issue-template-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Do not run `$rails s` on the terminal of vs code or other IDEs. This will output this error dues to wrong directory pointer. Use the default system Command Prompt. This helped to correct the error.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue and what resolved it for me was being sure that the capitalization of the directories for the file path in my terminal, which was running the server matched exactly (i.e. OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/blog, not onedrive/documents/github/blog).

Answer (score 0):

It's a very strange one. I had the same but instead make my controller name plural:

```sh
rails generate controller Welcomes index
```

And your routes.rb

```rb
# If this page will be your homepage ie /
root to: 'welcomes#index'
```

You'll notice your views becomes plural: `views/welcomes/index.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

In the VSCode the "views/layout" folder stands for views->layout subfolder. If you place your html file there, the controller will not find it. It is expected to be under "views"