# Rails 6.0.2 ActionMailer Issue: Template not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm in the development environment. When triggering an email in the UI, I get the error in the browser:

```
No template for interactive request
Admins::AdminsController#testmail is missing a template for request formats: text/html

NOTE!
Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name,
contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content),
which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser,
since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that's the case, carry on.
```

> The log shows:

```
Started GET "/en/admins/1/testmail" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-05 08:28:00 +0100
Processing by Admins::AdminsController#testmail as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en", "admin_id"=>"1"}
  Rendering test_mailer/testmail.text.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered test_mailer/testmail.text.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 4)
TestMailer#testmail: processed outbound mail in 2.0ms
Delivered mail 5e60aa00a74a7_20213ffce2ad423c8083a@domain.example.com.mail (59.0ms)
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 08:28:00 +0100
From: admin@domain.com
To: me@example.com
Message-ID: <5e60aa00a74a7_20213ffce2ad423c8083a@domain.example.com.mail.mail>
Subject: Welcome to My Awesome Site
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Welcome to example.com
===============================================
You have successfully signed up to example.com,
your username is: XXXX
To login to the site, just follow this link: .
Thanks for joining and have a great day!

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 64ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 3862)
ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (Admins::AdminsController#testmail is missing a template for request formats: text/html):
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:45:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
```

One can see above that the template is rendered before the error occurs.

> My Mailer class:

```
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def testmail
    mail(to: 'user@domain.com',
         subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site') do |format|
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

Of course the template is placed in `/app/views/test_mailer/testmail.text.erb`.

> My mail server config in development.rb is

I have mailcatcher running on localhost

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'localhost',
port: 1025
}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

I'm on a Centos 7, no special characters nor whitespaces in the whole Rails app path
Thanks for your investigations.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not the email that is sent successfully according to the log

the problem is you controller action Admins::AdminsController#testmail

doesn´t have a template in the views to render whatever html when a email is successfully sent

I suppose the path would be something like this:

```
/app/views/admins/admins/testmail.html.erb
```

Comment: Thanks @gabrimac, this was the correct path. 
I placed the template in about 3 other locations before (views/test_mailer  ,  views/admin/test_mailer ,  views/mailer ,  views/mailer/test_mailer ).. 
But your suggestion was now finally correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to generate your mailer in order to check you are not forgetting something:

```
bundle exec rails generate mailer mailer_classname mailer_viewname
```

Comment: I also tried your suggestion, with a namespaced admin mailer: `rails g mailer admins/x_class admins/x_view`. But this would put them into `app/views/admins` instead of `app/views/admins/admins`
but thanks as well.

Comment: could you try commenting   # layout 'mailer' in ApplicationMailer ?

Comment: No impact, still searches for the template in `views/admins/admins`.