# "No template for interactive request" when using Ruby on Rails on Powershell, but not on Command Prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell

When using Rails for the first time (well, the first time in a few years) I came across a confounding error. When following the [Getting Started turorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) exactly, I got this error:

[image: Error message: "No template for interactive request. ArticlesController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html. NOTE! Unless told otherwise, Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name, contained in a folder named after its controller. If this controller is an API responding with 204 (No Content), which does not require a template, then this error will occur when trying to access it via browser, since we expect an HTML template to be rendered for such requests. If that's the case, carry on."]

This persisted even when I deleted the project and tried again. However, after some searching online, I tried it in Command Prompt instead of Powershell, and voilà:

[image: Text: "Hello, Rails!"]

It's working now, but I'm confused about why it won't work on Powershell.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454289/13157676) was where I got the idea to try Command Prompt instead.

Comment: Please show the specific command you're using to start the server.

Comment: @mklment0 `ruby bin/rails server`

Comment: Assuming you've submitted the command from the _same_ directory in both cases, the call should work the same in PowerShell as it does in `cmd.exe`. Conceivably, your `cmd.exe` sessions have _environment variables_ defined that your PowerShell sessions don't, or perhaps the persistent environment variables were just changed (in the registry), and you haven't started a _new_ PowerShell session afterwards.